# Which cache-related HTTP request headers are the most frequently employed?

Tags: asp.net, http, caching

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037439/effective-meaning-of-http-cache-related-headers-in-asp-net) on cache-related HTTP headers and the browser behavior they cause.  To recap: I have a static file handler (.ashx) in an ASP.NET 2.0 web app that serves images.  I've just implemented support for cache-related headers, such as sending `cache-control`, `expires` and `last-modified`, and receiving/processing `if-modified-since`.

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9037530/412107) noted that there are several possible request headers to deal with, especially if [e-tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) are supported:

- If-Match
- If-Modified-Since
- If-None-Match
- If-Range
- If-Unmodified-Since

Besides `if-modified-since`, are there any that are frequently used?  Which other ones will yield the most benefits if supported server-side?

Comment: Have you investigated yslow? It's a great plugin for Firefox that will recommend cache headers for you. Check it out.